# How do I Spawn threads from two different objects and coordinate them in python v2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to combine the answers I got from two different python questions.

Here is the the first question and answer. Basically I just wanted to spawn two threads, one to powerDown() and the other to powerUp(), where powerUp() pends on powerDown()

[How to spawn a thread inside another thread in the same object in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18989472/how-to-spawn-a-thread-inside-another-thread-in-the-same-object-in-python)

```
import threading

class Server(threading.Thread):
    # some code
    def run(self):
        self.reboot()

    # This is the top level function called by other objects
    def reboot(self):
        # perhaps add a lock
        if not hasattr(self, "_down"):
            self._down = threading.Thread(target=self.__powerDown)
            self._down.start()
            up = threading.Thread(target=self.__powerUp)
            up.start()

    def __powerDown(self):
        # do something

    def __powerUp(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_down"):
            return
        self._down.join()
        # do something
        del self._down
```

---

Here is the the second question and answer. Basically I wanted to start a thread, and then call a function of the object.

[How to call a function on a running Python thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033818/how-call-a-function-on-a-running-thread-python)

```
import queue
import threading

class SomeClass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, q, loop_time = 1.0/60):
        self.q = q
        self.timeout = loop_time
        super(SomeClass, self).__init__()

    def onThread(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
        self.q.put((function, args, kwargs))

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                function, args, kwargs = self.q.get(timeout=self.timeout)
                function(*args, **kwargs)
            except queue.Empty:
                self.idle()

    def idle(self):
        # put the code you would have put in the `run` loop here 

    def doSomething(self):
        pass

    def doSomethingElse(self):
        pass
```

Here is combined idea code. Basically I wanted to spawn a thread, then then queue up a functions to execute, which in this case is reboot(). reboot() in turns creates two threads, the powerDown() and powerUp() threads, where powerDown() pends on powerUp()

```
import threading
import Queue

class Server(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, q, loop_time = 1.0/60):
        self.q = q
        self.timeout = loop_time
        super(Server, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                function, args, kwargs = self.q.get(timeout=self.timeout)
                function(*args, **kwargs)
            except queue.Empty:
                self.idle()

    def idle(self):
        # put the code you would have put in the `run` loop here 

    # This is the top level function called by other objects
    def reboot(self):
        self.__onthread(self.__reboot)

    def __reboot(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_down"):
            self._down = threading.Thread(target=self.__powerDown)
            self._down.start()
            up = threading.Thread(target=self.__powerUp)
            up.start()

    def __onThread(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
        self.q.put((function, args, kwargs))

    def __powerDown(self):
        # do something

    def __powerUp(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_down"):
            return
        self._down.join()
        # do something
        del self._down
```

All work, except when I create two Server subclasses.

```
class ServerA(Server):
    pass

class ServerB(Server):
    pass
```

Here is the code that instatiats both subclasses, and call the start() and reboot functions

```
serverA = ServerA(None)
serverB = ServerB(None)
serverA.start()
serverB.start()
serverA.reboot()
serverB.reboot()
```

I expect serverA.reboot() and serverB.reboot() to happen concurrently, which is what I want, but they DO NOT! serverB.reboot() gets executed after serverA.reboot() is done. That is, if I put print statements, I get

```
serverA started
serverB started
serverA.reboot() called
serverA.__powerDown called
serverA.__powerUp called
serverB.reboot() called
serverB.__powerDown called
serverB.__powerUp called
```

I know for a fact that it takes longer for ServerA to reboot, so I expect something like this

```
serverA started
serverB started
serverA.reboot() called
serverB.reboot() called
serverA.__powerDown called
serverB.__powerDown called
serverB.__powerUp called
serverA.__powerUp called
```

I hope that makes sense. If it does, why aren't my reboot() functions happening simultaneously?

Comment: If I just use the sample code from the first post, I can non-sequentially execute code; that is, I get my expected non-sequential powerDown/powerUp's from the two server objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you sending `None`  while you are expecting a queue object in the first place ? This causes an exception which complains that None type object doesn't have a get method. Besides that the exception you want to be handled in the `run` method is `Queue.Empty` and not `queue.Empty`.

Here is the revised code and its output on my machine:

```
import threading
import Queue

class Server(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, title, q, loop_time = 1.0/60):
        self.title = title
        self.q = q
        self.timeout = loop_time
        super(Server, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        print "%s started" % self.title
        while True:
            try:
                function, args, kwargs = self.q.get(timeout=self.timeout)
                function(*args, **kwargs)

            except Queue.Empty:
                # print "empty"
                self.idle()

    def idle(self):
        pass
        # put the code you would have put in the `run` loop here 

    # This is the top level function called by other objects
    def reboot(self):
        self.__onThread(self.__reboot)

    def __reboot(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_down"):
            self._down = threading.Thread(target=self.__powerDown)
            self._down.start()
            up = threading.Thread(target=self.__powerUp)
            up.start()

    def __onThread(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
        self.q.put((function, args, kwargs))

    def __powerDown(self):
        # do something
        print "%s power down" % self.title
        pass

    def __powerUp(self):
        print "%s power up" % self.title

        if not hasattr(self, "_down"):
            return

        self._down.join()
        # do something
        del self._down

class ServerA(Server):
    pass

class ServerB(Server):
    pass

def main():
    serverA = ServerA("A", Queue.Queue())
    serverB = ServerB("B", Queue.Queue())
    serverA.start()
    serverB.start()
    serverA.reboot()
    serverB.reboot()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
A started
B started

B power down
A power down
B power up
A power up
```

Comment: Yep that was the mistake! Thanks!